# How do I properly define the relationship between these classes created by EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

First of all apologies, this is a rookie question.

I'm trying to write a c# program that connects to an existing database and changes certain values based on user Input. (I know this may sound like a bad idea but we have our reasons…) I decided to use ef core to connect to the database.

I used `Scaffold-DbContext` to get the database structure into my program.
The build succeeded, however whenever I try to run my program I get the following error message:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'Dad.DadCmu' and 'DadCmu.IddadNavigation'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.'

So the relationship is not well defined I guess. Let's look at the classes then:

```
    public partial class DadCmu
    {
        public int Iddad { get; set; }
        public byte UnitNo { get; set; }

        public virtual Dad IddadNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

So IddadNavigation is of type Dad:

```
public partial class Dad
    {
        public Dad()
        {
            DadCh = new HashSet<DadCh>();
            DadConnection = new HashSet<DadConnection>();
        }

        public int Iddad { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? DadType { get; set; }
        public short? Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public byte? SynchronizationStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual DadCmu DadCmu { get; set; }
        public virtual DadMasCon DadMasCon { get; set; }
        public virtual DadOpc DadOpc { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DadCh> DadCh { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DadConnection> DadConnection { get; set; }
    }
```

And their relationship should be defined within `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        …
        modelBuilder.Entity<DadCmu>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Iddad);

                entity.ToTable("DadCMU");

                entity.Property(e => e.Iddad)
                    .HasColumnName("IDDad")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.HasOne(d => d.IddadNavigation)
                    .WithOne(p => p.DadCmu)
                    .HasForeignKey<DadCmu>(d => d.Iddad)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_DadCMU_Dad");
            });
        …
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dad>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Iddad);

                entity.Property(e => e.Iddad).HasColumnName("IDDad");

                entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdate).HasColumnType("datetime");
            });
        …
        }
```

So here within `modelBuilder.Entity<DadCmu>` it does explicitly mention a foreign key so I'm not quite sure what the problem is?
Do I have to do the same within `modelBuilder.Entity<Dad>`?

What would that code look like?

Or am I misunderstanding the problem entirely?

Is this something that can be done automatically, e.g. with a parameter for `scaffold-dbcontext`? (My DB has 180 tables and I get the same error for many of them.)

And is this all possible without changing the structure of the db itself?

Thank you so much in Advance! Again, this is my first time working with databases so I apologize if this really obvious.

**Edit:**
Class DadOpc which came up in comments:

```
    public partial class DadOpc
    {
        public int Iddad { get; set; }
        public string Computer { get; set; }
        public string OpcserviceName { get; set; }
        public float? ScanInterval { get; set; }
        public byte? ServerType { get; set; }
        public byte? UseSecurity { get; set; }

        public virtual Dad IddadNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit 2:** (regarding jcruz' solution)

Error message:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'DadMasCon.IddadNavigation' and 'Dad.DadMasCon'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.'

Class Dad:

```
public partial class Dad
    {
        public Dad()
        {
            DadCh = new HashSet<DadCh>();
            DadConnection = new HashSet<DadConnection>();
        }

        //user added Id-Fields:
        public int DadCmuId { get; set; }
        public int DadOpcId { get; set; }
        public int DadMasConId { get; set; }


        public int Iddad { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? DadType { get; set; }
        public short? Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public byte? SynchronizationStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual DadCmu DadCmu { get; set; }
        public virtual DadMasCon DadMasCon { get; set; }
        public virtual DadOpc DadOpc { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DadCh> DadCh { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DadConnection> DadConnection { get; set; }
    }
```

Class DadMasCon:

```
        public DadMasCon()
        {
            DadModbusRegConfig = new HashSet<DadModbusRegConfig>();
        }

        public int Iddad { get; set; }
        public int UnitNo { get; set; }
        public byte? Model { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RefTimeOffset { get; set; }
        public float? TimeoutComm { get; set; }
        public int? Port { get; set; }
        public float? ConnectionInterval { get; set; }
        public byte? ExternalComm { get; set; }
        public string Mvbparameters { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusBps { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusParity { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusStopBits { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusMode { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusSlaveAddress { get; set; }
        public byte? CardType0 { get; set; }
        public byte? CardType1 { get; set; }
        public byte? CardType2 { get; set; }
        public byte? CardType3 { get; set; }
        public string LastIp { get; set; }
        public string HiddenParameter { get; set; }
        public int? SerialNo { get; set; }
        public int? LastSequence { get; set; }
        public int? TcppackageErrors { get; set; }
        public byte? UsePrivateFirmware { get; set; }
        public byte? ConfigurationLock { get; set; }
        public byte? IecclientOn { get; set; }
        public string IecclientAddress { get; set; }
        public string IecclientDomain { get; set; }
        public byte? IecsrvOn { get; set; }
        public byte? IecsrvNrOfClents { get; set; }
        public string IecsrvAuthentication { get; set; }
        public string Iecmmsparam { get; set; }
        public float? IecclientPollInterval { get; set; }
        public byte? NtpserverType { get; set; }
        public string Ntpipaddress { get; set; }
        public string IecmmsparamFileName { get; set; }
        public string ModbusTcpaddress { get; set; }
        public int? ModbusTcpportNr { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusByteOrder { get; set; }
        public byte? ModbusClientValueType { get; set; }
        public string Macaddress { get; set; }
        public byte? MonitorInitiate { get; set; }

        public virtual Dad IddadNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DadModbusRegConfig> DadModbusRegConfig { get; set; }
    }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DadMasCon>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Iddad)
                    .HasName("PK_DadMasCon16");

                entity.Property(e => e.Iddad)
                    .HasColumnName("IDDad")
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.IecclientAddress).HasColumnName("IECClientAddress");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecclientDomain).HasColumnName("IECClientDomain");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecclientOn).HasColumnName("IECClientOn");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecclientPollInterval).HasColumnName("IECClientPollInterval");

                entity.Property(e => e.Iecmmsparam).HasColumnName("IECMMSParam");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecmmsparamFileName).HasColumnName("IECMMSParamFileName");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecsrvAuthentication).HasColumnName("IECSrvAuthentication");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecsrvNrOfClents).HasColumnName("IECSrvNrOfClents");

                entity.Property(e => e.IecsrvOn).HasColumnName("IECSrvOn");

                entity.Property(e => e.Macaddress).HasColumnName("MACAddress");

                entity.Property(e => e.ModbusTcpaddress)
                    .HasColumnName("ModbusTCPAddress")
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.ModbusTcpportNr).HasColumnName("ModbusTCPPortNr");

                entity.Property(e => e.Mvbparameters).HasColumnName("MVBParameters");

                entity.Property(e => e.Ntpipaddress).HasColumnName("NTPIPAddress");

                entity.Property(e => e.NtpserverType).HasColumnName("NTPServerType");

                entity.Property(e => e.RefTimeOffset).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.TcppackageErrors).HasColumnName("TCPPackageErrors");

                //user generated:
                entity.HasOne(d => d.IddadNavigation)
                    .WithOne(p => p.DadMasCon)
                    .HasForeignKey<Dad>(d => d.DadMasConId);

                //original:
                //entity.HasOne(d => d.IddadNavigation)
                //    .WithOne(p => p.DadMasCon)
                //    .HasForeignKey<DadMasCon>(d => d.Iddad)
                //    .HasConstraintName("FK_DadMasCon_Dad");
            });
```

Comment: Fluent configuration looks ok. What is the EF Core version?

Comment: @IvanStoev 3.1.0

Comment: You can always do everything without changing db.
        [Key]
        [Column("IdDad")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
Here is the other syntax that can achieve the same, mabye you will have more luck  with this

Comment: Can't reproduce. Copied the classes and fluent configuration from the post, commented out navigation properties to entities not included in the post, and everything (migration, query) works (no exceptions). Is there something custom not shown here (additional properties in partial class extensions, derived classes etc.)?

Comment: @ThomasKoelle just so I understand this correctly: I could write this instead of `public int Iddad { get; set; }`. Everything functions the same but my id-Variable within the program is then called 'Id' instead of 'Iddad', correct? I'm somewhat reluctant to do this as I have a **lot** of tables but good to know, thank you!

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you so much for taking the time and trying my solution out! There are lots of other classes that also use e.g. an IddadNavigation variable of type Dad such as this one: ``` public partial class DadCh { public int IddadCh { get; set; } public int Iddad { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } ... public virtual Dad IddadNavigation { get; set; } public virtual DadChCmu DadChCmu { get; set; } ... }``` I'm not sure this qualifies?

Comment: Lots? According to the model, only `DadCh` and `DadConnection` classes should have such navigation property. While `DadMasCon` and `DadOpc` should have property of type `ICollection<Dad>`. Is that correct?

Comment: `DadMasCon`has `public virtual Dad IddadNavigation { get; set; }`.
The only ICollection it contains is
`public virtual ICollection<DadModbusRegConfig> DadModbusRegConfig { get; set; }`.
`DadOpc` also has `public virtual Dad IddadNavigation { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to define a one-to-one relationship you need to explicitly define the back reference id on your `Dad` model to ensure it maps to a single `DadCmu` record.

```
public partial class Dad
{
    public int DadCmuId { get; set; }
    public virtual DadCmu DadCmu { get; set; }
}
```

You can then configure this using the fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DadCmu>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.IddadNavigation)
          .WithOne(p => p.DadCmu)
          .HasForeignKey<Dad>(d => d.DadCmuId);
});
```

HTH

Comment: Just making sure I understand: Basically EF Core's scaffold compared to your answer is missing an id which you have manually added (the `DadCmuId`). Part two then is defining the relationship via the HasOne...WithOne… syntax.
Your solution makes sense to me, I'm just not sure why EF Core's code is wrong?
Anyway, I have implemented this and now I get a different error (well, same error but pertaining different classes) so I'll keep doing that. If this fixes my issue I will accept your answer. Might take until tuesday though.

Comment: Update: After applying this to 7 different classes the error message now remains the same, pertaining a class which I already "fixed" so unless I messed up somewhere this does not seem to work.
Will add the classes to the OP.

Comment: @RD It is still missing configuration for your navigation properties/relationship. Since `DadCmuId` is being explicitly defined, I can only think its the other side. It can be that the standard EF conventions (example: `IddadNavigation` => `IddadNavigation_Id`) don't match your setup. What is the column name or property that is the key for `IddadNavigation`?

Comment: `IddadNavigation` is of type `Dad` which has the primary key `Iddad`.
I don't quite follow as far as what is missing in the relationship between `Dad` and `DadMasCon`.
`Dad` contains a property of type `DadMasCon` as well as `DadMasConId`. `DadMasCon` contains a property of type `Dad`.
Within `OnModelCreating` the line `entity.HasOne(d => d.IddadNavigation)
                    .WithOne(p => p.DadMasCon)
                    .HasForeignKey<Dad>(d => d.DadMasConId);` should now define `DadMasConId`as the foreign key, right?